# How do i write C code without using a goto keyword?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, logic, goto

I have this code written using a goto keyword:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        int i,j,k;
         for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
         {
         for(j=1;j<=3;j++)
         {
         for(k=1;k<=3;k++)
         {
         [***if(i==2&&j==2&&k==2)
         
           goto out;][1]
         else
         printf("%d %d %d\n ",i,j,k);***
        }
        }
       }
       out:
       printf("\nOut of the loop");
        return 0;
    }
```

And I have tried to write it without using goto with help of if statement and switch case. But I couldn't come with perfect logic. Please, someone, help me with this one.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
        int i,j,k;
         for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
         {
         for(j=1;j<=3;j++)
         {
         for(k=1;k<=3;k++)
         {
         if(i>=2&&j>=2&&k>=2)
         break;
         else
         printf("%d %d %d\n ",i,j,k);
    
        }
        **

**switch(i>=2&&j>=3&&k>=1)
        {
        case 1: break;
        default : break;
     }**

**
     }
        switch(i>=3&&j>=2&&k>=2)
        {
        case 1: break;
        default : break;
     }
     }
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Don't add formatting in code snippets. Add comments on lines you want to point out, and explanations for those lines in the question if you need to say more about them.

Comment: As for breaking out of multiple levels of nested loops, first of all try to avoid nested loops as much as you can, and you simply won't have that problem. For example you could use functions that contains a loop instead, and check the functions return value. Otherwise use extra state variables and `if` checks in the outer loops.

Comment: The first rule to prevent goto's is to restructure the code. Then, there are two cases where a goto is allowed in C: to break out of inner loops and for error handling. Both cases could require lots of state variables and other artificial (unreadable, processor cycles consuming) constructs to prevent a goto.

Comment: Would you mind if I fixed the indentation? My eyes hurt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another variable and use it to "notify" the loops that they should end.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    int run_me = 1;
    for (i = 1; run_me && i <= 3; i++) {
      for (j = 1; run_me && j <= 3; j++) {
        for (k = 1; run_me && k <= 3; k++) {
          if (i == 2 && j == 2 && k == 2) {
             run_me = 0;
          } else {
             printf("%d %d %d\n ",i,j,k);***
          }
        }
      }
   }
   printf("\nOut of the loop");
   return 0;
}
```

You can create a function from the loops.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void function(void) 
{
    int i,j,k;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        for (k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
          if (i == 2 && j == 2 && k == 2) {
             return;
          } else {
             printf("%d %d %d\n ",i,j,k);***
          }
        }
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
   function();
   printf("\nOut of the loop");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the control variable inside the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            if ((i == 2) && (j == 2) && (k == 2)) {
                // change control variables to finish their loop
                k = j = i = 9; break; // exit all loops
            }
            printf("%d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be considered a _hack_ and is not general use, the loops could be not `for` loops but `while` loops.  Then you have to write a statement that makes all of them fail, and that in general is not possible.